# Loops in Robinson arithmetic

Tags: axioms, peano-axioms, formal-systems

In the [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic#Axioms), I wonder how the recursive definition of addition and multiplication can be well-defined.

Axiom 3 seems to prohibit other chains starting with an element which has no successor.

But it doesn't prohibit loops or chains which are infinite in both directions.

E.g. why should the following

$$ 0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow  \cdots \\
\\
  a {\rightarrow \atop \leftarrow} b$$

(that means Sa = b and Sb = a) not be compatible with Robinson arithmetic?

Comment: This answer seems to cover your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1066378/197161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article,in the section Metamathematics, 4th paragraph, it states that the axioms cannot disprove $x=Sx,$ which I think should say "cannot disprove $\exists x\;(x=Sx).$"

Comment: Sorry .I am deleting that part, but leaving the second part.

Comment: So, there can be loops?

Comment: I dk whether this means there can be loops of longer length, but I would guess so.