# (Peano axioms) Showing why the induction axiom is necessary

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

On pg no. 3 of [this](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~robertop/Courses/TMP/7_Peano_Axioms.pdf) article, the author says

> let’s consider this version of $\Bbb{N}$ that satisfies all the above axioms, but is not the usual natural numbers we know: $\Bbb{N}=\{0,1,2,3,...,\} ∪\{a,b\}$. That is, this version of $\Bbb{N}$ contains all the natural numbers and also includes two other symbols, $a$ and $b$.

My question is if $a, b \notin  \Bbb{N}$, then where do $a$ and $b$ belong? Also, if the above argument in the article is wrong, can you please provide another argument to show why the induction axiom is necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the post [Model of Robinson Arithmetic but not Peano Arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066087/model-of-robinson-arithmetic-but-not-peano-arithmetic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a$ and $b$ are not among the natural numbers that we're used to, but they are part of these non-standard natural numbers, specifically to demonstrate that without the axiom of induction, we allow some really strange notions of what "natural number" means.