# Is there a noncommutative model of PA - Induction

Tags: model-theory

This is an exercise in the book "A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic" (Authors: Christopher Leary and Lars Kristiansen).

Let $N$ be the peano axioms without the induction axiom, i.e., there are 11 axioms:

1. $(\forall x)\neg Sx=0.$
2. $(\forall x)(\forall y)\left[Sx=Sy\longrightarrow x=y\right].$
3. $(\forall x)x+0=x.$
4. $(\forall x)(\forall y)x + Sx = S(x+y).$
5. $(\forall x)x\cdot0=0.$
6. $(\forall x)(\forall y)x\cdot Sy=(x\cdot y)+x.$
7. $(\forall x)xE0=S0.$
8. $(\forall x)(\forall y)xE(Sy)=(xEy)\cdot x.$
9. $(\forall x)\neg x<0.$
10. $(\forall x)(\forall y)\left[x<Sy\longleftrightarrow \left(x<y\vee x=y\right)\right].$
11. $(\forall x)(\forall y)\left[\left(x<y\right)\vee\left(x=y\right)\vee\left(y<x\right)\right].$

The exercise asks for a structure $\mathfrak{M}$ such that $\mathfrak{M}\models N$ and $\mathfrak{M}\models\neg(\forall x)(\forall y)[x+y=y+x]$

I do not know whether it is a trivial question; I hope it is not. I have tried to construct this model, but I could not. I see the universe as matrices or functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ and define $+$ as composition, but I could not define $S$ such that the axioms 1 and 4 are both satisfied.

I also thought that we could prove the commutativity for adding two numbers like $SS\dots S0$ in a finite number of steps (it is just intuition), so I added an element that does not have a predecessor. But I could not define the functions as wanted in this case either. My other attempts are also failed.

Comment: Do you know about the ordinals? The ordinals with their standard operations are a model of this. (Or the countable ordinals, to make it set-sized.) And ordinal addition doesn't commute.

Comment: Yes, this is a good example, thank you. But I would like to see much smaller models. In the previous example of the book, to show that it does not prove $(\forall x)\neg x<x$, it constructs a model using the universe $\mathbb{N}\cup\{a\}$. I believe that there is a solution using a similar method...

Comment: I think a model like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1066378) one with two extra elements will work with exponentiation as well if you make a good choice for the multiplication table